# How to print elements in slice without bracket in Go line by line?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var s []int
    s = append(s, 2, 3, 4)
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/tx8gmx5eR7B

Output:

```
len=3 cap=4 [2 3 4]
```

Output should be:

```
2
3
4
```

I want it without loop.

Comment: Write your own output in a loop.

Comment: `fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), strings.NewReplacer("[", "", "]", "").Replace(fmt.Sprintf("%v", s))`

Comment: There needs to be a loop somewhere, whether a simple for loop is harder to read than  hiding with something like `strings.Join(strings.Split(strings.Trim(fmt.Sprintf("%v", s), "[]"), " "), "\n")` is up to you I guess

Comment: It is literally impossible to do this without a loop. Even your solution has a loop, it's just hidden from your eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> print elements in slice without bracket in Go line by line.
>
> Comment: I want it without loop

---

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func printSlice(s []int) {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(s[0])
    printSlice(s[1:])
}

func main() {
    var s []int
    s = append(s, 2, 3, 4)
    printSlice(s)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ISXdbjTrfSt

Output:

```
2
3
4
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this is a dramatically worse solution than just using a loop.

Comment: That _is_ a loop. It's just hidden in a recursive function.

Comment: I usually like your answers, but this one is abysmal :(  It implies it works without a loop, but it doesn't. And it should come with bold warnings that this is a bad approach.

Comment: I would say maybe not-so-good old `goto` might be more performant than this, but loop is still the best solution.

Comment: @Flimzy: Really! In mathematics and computer science, both iteration and recursion are distinct and important. The accepted answer is a good solution to the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Create the string with the values and brackets. 
Print the substring not including the brackets, and voilà.
Or use `strings.Trim` as suggested by JimB in the comment.

```golang
temp := fmt.Sprintf("%v", s)
fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d \n%v\n", len(s), cap(s), strings.Join(strings.Split(temp[1:len(temp)-1], " "), "\n"))
```

Outputs:

```
len=3 cap=4 
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work if you don't want to use fmt.Println and only use printf and range over the slice without calculating len.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var s []int
    s = append(s, 2, 3, 4)
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
       for _, value:= range s {
         fmt.Printf("%v\n", value)
       }
}
```

update: I haven't read your comments section while posting this , without for loop answer from peterSO works great and nice answer too.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the only sane way to do it. peterSO's solution is not nice, it's far less efficient, harder to read, and hides the loop (which is still there).

Comment: @Flimzy agreed, that answer gives a different approach and atleast on first look it looked nice to me though it is not if you look in depth.

Comment: @cslrnr: `fmt.Printf("%v\n", value)` is equivalent to `fmt.Println(value)`. Use `fmt.Println(value)`, it is easier to optimize and it is more readable.

Comment: @cslrnr: Look at the question from a computer science perspective. The OP asked for an improved algorithm. Flimzy suggested using iteration (a loop). The OP then asked for a non-iterative (without a loop) or recursive algorithm. I provided a recursive algorithm, which the OP accepted. Flimzy claims that recursion is iteration ("That is a loop. It's just hidden in a recursive function"). In computer science, iteration and recursion are distinct mechanisms. You provided an iterative algorithm. The OP asked for a non-iterative algorithm.

Comment: @peterSO, I don't have objection on your answer that's accepted by user or why it is accepted. Still I am with flimzy on the comments he made about recursion

Comment: @Flimzy: The OP asked for and accepted a solution "without loop." If a professor, potential employer, or anyone else asks for a non-iterative (without loop, without while, for, or do) solution they want a recursive solution. An iterative solution will get an F, and does not get a job offer.

Comment: @peterSO: If the answer were accompanied by due comments explaining why it's a bad solution, I wouldn't have a problem with it.